# All super classes of a class using ASM java Byte Code

Tags: java-bytecode-asm

How to get All super classes of a class using ASM java Byte Code ?

Answer (score 2):

```
package com.eg.agent;

import java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer;
import java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException;
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader;

public class EgClassFileTransformer implements ClassFileTransformer {

    protected String agentArgString = "";
    protected Instrumentation instrumentation;

    public EgClassFileTransformer(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst){
        agentArgString = agentArgs;
        instrumentation = inst;
        instrumentation.addTransformer(this);
    }

    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined, 
            ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException
        {
            //System.out.println("ClassName :"+className);
            InputStream in = loader.getResourceAsStream(className.replace('.', '/') + ".class");
            try{
                ClassReader classReader=new ClassReader(in);
                String superClassName = classReader.getSuperName();
                String[] interfaces = classReader.getInterfaces();
                if(interfaces!=null && interfaces.length > 0){
                    for(int k=0;k<interfaces.length;k++){
                        String inface = interfaces[k];
                        System.out.println(" \t interface :"+inface);
                    }
                }
                //System.out.println("superClassName :"+superClassName);
                ArrayList thisList = new ArrayList();
                thisList.add(superClassName);
                ArrayList superList = printSuperClassNames(superClassName , thisList);
                System.out.println("className :"+className +" ==>"+ " superList :"+superList);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("[EXECEPTION] ..."+className);
            }
            return null;
        }

    public static ArrayList printSuperClassNames(String className, ArrayList list)
    {
        ClassReader cr=null;
        try {
            cr = new ClassReader(className);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String superName = cr.getSuperName();
        //System.out.println("[superName]"+superName);
        if(superName!=null && !superName.equals("java/lang/Object"))
        {
            list.add(superName);
            String superClass = superName.replace('.', '/');
            printSuperClassNames(superClass, list);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way of doing this would be to visit the bytecode of the constructor of a class and record the first constructor invoke instruction i.e. `invokespecial` call you can find. That should give you the name of class that is a `super` to the current class of interest.

Comment: Hi vijay, thanks for your help.. I do it in the following manner. is it ok?

Comment: hey @RameshSubramanian ... i think your solution should work. i have not run it or anything, but using the ClassReader should work out fine. It was silly of me not to think of this simpler solution. Kudos to you for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little tricky, since a class file only contains the immediate super class. Therefore, you'll have to recursively read all super classes.

You can do this by processing each class with a ClassVisitor with an overridden visit(int version, int access, String name, String signature, String superName, String[] interfaces) method to read the super class name.

Pseudo Code:

```
List<String> getSuperClasses(className){
  superClass=getSuperClass(className)
  return superClass+getSuperClasses(superClass)
}

String getSuperClass(className) {
  cw=new ClassWriter()
  v=new SuperClassReadingClassVisitor(cw)
  new ClassReader(className).accept(v)
  return v.superClass
}

class SuperClassReadingClassVisitor{
  String superClass
  @Override
  visit(int version, int access, String name, String signature, String superName, String[] interfaces) {
  superClass=superName
  super.visit(version, access, name, ...)
}
```

Comment: Hi ruediste, thank you very much, let me try with this in my bytecode injection

Comment: Hi rudiste, thanks for your ans.. I do it in the following manner. is it ok? or is there any simple way to get all super class names?